# Filter goes beyond the grid in jqxgrid

Tags: filter, jqxgrid

filter goes beyond the grid in jqxgrid hence unable to perform the filter action.

Please refer the attachment.

[image: jxgrid]

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Have used jqwidgets version v2.9.1 with jquery-1.10.1.min.js